# How to find DynamoDB table created by @model GraphQL api in Amplify?

Tags: aws-amplify, amazon-dynamodb

My understanding is that when creating objects annotated with @model in GraphQL API, DynamoDB table is created and configured automatically. How to access this table? I cannot see it in the DynamoDB console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should be there. Make sure you are in the same region as your Amplify application. So for example, if you provisioned your Amplify app in us-east-2,  your DynamoDB tables will also be in us-east-2.